# java.io.NotSerializableException in java code?

Tags: java, serialization

I have class where all the inner classes are seralized something like this

```
public class BaseClass{
.......
......
.......
public class AccountPaymentDetailBean implements Serializable {
//inner class 
}

}
```

But i am getting below exception

> java.io.NotSerializableException: com.core.shi.core.folder.BaseClass$5
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractPage.writeObject(AbstractPage.java:232)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1118)   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.writeObject(DesktopImpl.java:1044)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
>     at org.zkoss.util.CacheMap.writeObject(CacheMap.java:633)   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SimpleSession.writeThis(SimpleSession.java:433)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession.writeObject(SerializableSession.java:71)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at
>   com.csdcsystems.amanda.servlet.AmandaSessionFilter.sizeof(AmandaSessionFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.csdcsystems.amanda.servlet.AmandaSessionFilter.testSerializability(AmandaSessionFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   com.csdcsystems.amanda.servlet.AmandaSessionFilter.doFilter(AmandaSessionFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Could someone please tell me what is meaning of  **BaseClass$5** ? What this exception exactly telling ?

Comment: reference of base class instance to access base class fields and data, that is synthetic field generated by compiler

Comment: BaseClass$5 is a représentation of your object. BaseClass = instance of BaseClass class and 5 is the result of hashCode() method.

Comment: Much better defintion

Comment: @zatenzu no, it's not. `BaseClass$5` means that there is an anonymous class inside of BaseClass and the compiler choose the name "5" for this class. Hashcode of objects is prefixed with `@`.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Damned! Sorry for my mistake. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone please tell me what is meaning of BaseClass$5?

*The fifth anonymous inner class defined in BaseClass.*

Anonymous inner classes are assigned an automatic name equal to the enclosing type, plus a dollar symbol, plus an ordinal. In your example: "BaseClass" + "$" + "5".

> What this exception exactly telling?

- Apparently the framework you are using is testing the serializability of the HTTP session (`com.csdcsystems.amanda.servlet.AmandaSessionFilter.testSerializability`)
- AND your session (of type `org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession`) appears to have an anonymous `BaseClass$5` defined inside.
- Every object in a session must be serializable, so that's why you get this error.

Answer (score 2):

**Q2) What this exception exactly telling ?** 
Inner classes should not implement Serializable. They use compiler-generated synthetic fields to store references to enclosing instances and to store values of local variables from enclosing scopes. 
The default serialized form of an inner class is illdefined. A static member class can, however, implement Serializable.

More information [here.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/SER05-J.+Do+not+serialize+instances+of+inner+classes)

**Q1) Could someone please tell me what is meaning of BaseClass$5 ?** 
There is no more further details. BAseClass$5 mean these exception occured in this class.

Comment: But i have forcefully implemented Serialization so every class in my project Searlizable

Comment: I already mean, if inner class want to implements, this should be static. eg. public static class AccountPaymentDetailBean implements Serializable {

Comment: But i am already doing like i mentioned i am not getting any issue

Comment: @subodh Do you use an anonymous class?

Comment: No i did not used any anonymous class

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Could someone please tell me what is meaning of BaseClass$5 ? 
  sometimes innerclasses do not have names .
   in your case it has a name.
  A case where we directly create a class (e.g. implementor of a interface) on-the-fly and give implementation, and finish it with :); then
 that class does not gets a name. 
SO how do JVM creates a .class file for that???
  - answer is $ naming convention.
  so such classes gets created as BaseClass$1, BaseClass$2 ...so on.

There must be at least 5 such inner unnames classes - check in your classes - which one gets which number?-> **I think** its purely on sequence.
e.g. - clickListener is purely fictitious, example I tried to show...

```
public class myclass{
    public void mymethod(){
          this.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){
               public void click(){
                   S.O.P("Clicked !!!");
               }
          });
    }
}
```

So the implementation CLickListener gets compiled to->
 myclass$1.class